# Unable to send mail in python on Outlook with the smtplib

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

I try to send email via an Outlook account, but I am unable to. I successfully did sent email with Gmail, but I am unable to with Outlook.

I tried tried to change the host and port between 
SMTP.office365.com Port : 587
and ..

smtp-mail.outlook.com Port : 587
not working. Same error.

Gmail sending :

```py
def sendmail(from_email, password, to_email, subject, message):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) #Info pour send depuis une addresse courriel
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(from_email, password)
        server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
        server.close
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Something went wrong :", str(e))
        return False

sendmail('email@gmail.com', 'password', 'email1@gmail.com', 'subject', 'this is message body ; so hot ! ')
```

Outlook "sending" :

```py
def sendmail(from_email, password, to_email, subject, message):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('SMTP.office365.com', 587) #Info pour send depuis une addresse courriel
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(from_email, password)
        server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())
        server.close
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Something went wrong :", str(e))
        return False

sendmail('email@outlook.com', 'password', 'email1@gmail.com', 'subject', 'this is message body ; so hot ! ')
```

Excepted : Mail sending on email1@gmail.com

Error : Something went wrong : [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1056)

When I delete _SSL, an error occure;

Something went wrong : SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Comment: Check to make sure the SMTP server and ports are correct. Also check if the provider will allow a rely. The error is typical of not being able to connect to the server. Since you are able to send using gmail the code does work.

Comment: server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587) works with no error. The error occure in server.login(from_email, password)

Error : SMPTP AUTH Extension not supported by server

Comment: Solution found : missing server.starttls