# Not able to Send mail to Outlook.com via SMTP in Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am able to send the mail to gmail account via SMTP in Python. But when tried doing the same for Outlook - office365, it is throwing the error.

Code to send mail to gmail (working)

```
import smtplib
sender_email = "ABC@gmail.com"
rec_email = "ABC@gmail.com"
password = input(str("pwd:"))
message = "hey sent using python"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email,password)
print("Login success")
server.sendmail(sender_email,rec_email, message)
print("Email sent to",rec_email)
```

code for Outlook(throwing error)

```
import smtplib
sender_email = "ABC@companydomain.com"
rec_email = "ABC@companydomain.com"
password = input(str("pwd:"))
message = "hey sent using python"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.outlook.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email,password)
print("Login success")
server.sendmail(sender_email,rec_email, message)
print("Email sent to",rec_email )
```

The following error occurs when i run the above outlook code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ABC/Python/Python37/pythonmail.py", line 32, in <module>
  server.login(sender_email,password)
File "C:\Users\ABC\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 730, in login
  raise last_exception
File "C:\Users\ABC\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 721, in login
  initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
File "C:\Users\ABC\Python\Python37\lib\smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
  raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful 
  [BM1PR01CA0154.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]')
```

i even went through the following links:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203843/unable-to-send-mail-in-python-on-outlook-with-the-smtplib][1]

[https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1961/][2]

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061531/send-mail-from-alias-mail-id-using-python-smtplib][2]

Can somebody help me on how to fix the error??

Meanwhile the below code worked for both gmail and outlook using win32com.client. But i want to do it with SMTP lib. Kindly help

```
import win32com.client as client
outlook = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
message.To = 'ABC@domain.com'
message.subject = 'Test Mail'
message.body = 'Sending a test mail :)'
message.send
print("mail sent successfully")
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission

Comment: I bet your company email account has SMTP authentication disabled, is on a different port or requires the creation of a separate password or something. Just google "outlook.com allow SMTP". Should lead you to the goal

Comment: Thanks for the help. Lets say my company has disabled SMTP authentication. Then is there any other way to send the mail to outlook through Python without SMTP?? Could you please help!!

Comment: Why does the win32com not work for you?

Comment: when win32com is used, the mail is sent outlook only if outlook application is open. If it is closed mail wont be sent. Hence chose to work with SMTP.

Comment: @FloLie thanks for your comments, I tried by without giving port number and password and it worked for me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Tried by not giving port number and password. It worked.

```
import smtplib
sender_email = "test_mail@company.com"
rec_email = ["ABC@company.com"]
message = "hey sent using python"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.corp.company.com')
print("Login success")
server.sendmail(sender_email,rec_email, message)
print("Email sent to",rec_email )
```

Comment: How and why did it work without the password? Isn't this an exploitable security issue?

Comment: I'm facing below error without giving port num and password, can you suggest any idea! @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9433688/swetha-reddy
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond